# Re-firing MouseListener event

Tags: java, swing

I need to store a mouse click event whenever a user clicks on a table column for sorting.

I'm basically saving the MouseEven:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e_)
```

I store e_ on a global variable so later I can fire that same event and sort the table to the previous user sort action.

But when I manually fire the previous stored mouse event the table does not get sorted.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(_mouseEvent);
```

So basically this is how I want it to work. User clicks on a JTable column for sorting. 
I store the created MouseEvent on a global variable.  When the JTable gets re-created, I need it to be set to the previous sort action.
This is why I need to re-fire the stored MouseEvent but its not working.  Any ideas?

Comment: The fact that you are recreating the table when the user clicks on the TableHeader for sorting makes me uncomfortable, this feels like a code-smell/warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with mouse event. You have to store the state of your row sorter. Take a look at [RowSorter API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html). You can retrieve and restore this state by using `getSortKeys()` and  `setSortKeys()` methods. Obviously can get RowSorter from your table using `getRowSorter()`method.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

See the sort() method of the DefaultRowSorter.